# Facebook Graph API - Page request limited reached but have page_engaged_users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an application that manages 100+ Facebook pages. On some page I'm getting the following error:

```
{ 
  message: '(#32) Page request limited reached',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 32,
  fbtrace_id: 'CzEElQoxHuu'
}
```

The pages that display this message have `page_engaged_users` over the previous 24 hours.

I understand that from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) if I have a single `page_engaged_users` I should be able to make 4800 requests. However each Facebook Page is making a max of 390 API requests per 24 hours.

Does anyone know that if I have at least one `page_engaged_users` in the previous 24 hours I can make up to 4800 requests?

I can't seem to find any contact information for Facebook to support ticket forum etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that this quota is shared between all apps that perform management tasks on the page. So if some of those pages use other apps as well, your app is “competing” with those.

Comment: I see what you mean but the problem is all the pages that I'm managing are using the same app.

Comment: But are they using _only_ this app?

Comment: Good point. I'm not aware of any other apps being used but I would have to investigate further, Thanks for the tip